# Docker container Microsoft Health OSS packages 401 (Unauthorized - No local versions of package 'commandlineparser';)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

Since the beginning of this week, the docker container of my project stopped building. I'm using Micrsoft Health OSS packages in my project. From some point it started returning error when restoring packages within the docker container. The errors are following:

```
#0 2.601   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized - No local versions of package 'commandlineparser'; please provide authentication to access versions from upstream that have not yet been saved to your feed. (DevOps Activity ID: 4BA31926-C9E8-4F86-9E59-142E0DA64FA7)).
#0 2.861   Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.3.1.9' from 'https://microsofthealthoss.pkgs.visualstudio.com/7621b231-1a7d-4364-935b-2f72b911c43d/_packaging/a60b7c8b-c6ae-4a8e-bd15-a526b603a1f2/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.extensions.logging/3.1.9/microsoft.extensions.logging.3.1.9.nupkg'.
#0 2.861   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized - No local versions of package 'microsoft.extensions.logging'; please provide authentication to access versions from upstream that have not yet been saved to your feed. (DevOps Activity ID: 76F6CE40-D628-4ED1-A80B-CB3410AFF5F0)).
```

it was working fine few days ago and nothing has been changes on my side. When I grab the latest code for the Microsoft FHIR-Converter project locally and try to build - the packages are restored successfully. There is no issue when restoring the packages locally using the project file without the docker container.
During the investigation and research I have looked into a similar topic, however I'm not finding it useful in any way: [Azure DevOps: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized - No local versions of package 'skiasharp')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76640185/azure-devops-response-status-code-does-not-indicate-success-401-unauthorized/76662452#76662452)

Is this related specifically to a docker container?